# Error when adding webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, share

When tried to add webpart to a page, user is getting the below (screen shot) error and not able to add the webpart.

Note : Another user tried to add webpart in the same page and got the same error

[image]

Comment: Can you also add some code here ? Looks like some issue in disposing the objects.

Comment: use exception handling in your code and then add it.

Answer (score 0):

Either this Web part is a custom one and has not been development correctly: it disposes (i.e. use of `SPWeb.Dispose`) the contextual `SPWeb` object (the one from `SPCOntext.Current`).

Or the problem can be in another custom Web part placed on the page before the new one. That first Web part has the problem of disposing the contextual `SPWeb` but this only impacts (randomly, because of memory management mechanisms) the Web parts after it.

So, it is most probably a coding error in a custom Web part. This needs a code review on it.